# Display href link into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the `href` link in the `<div id="display"></div>` tag so when I press anything in the menu or in my list it'll just open in the div with `display` as its `id`.
I have this menu like this done

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onkeydown="myFunc()">HOME</a>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

and my JavaScript is like this

```
$('#display').html($('.menu a').html());
```

I don't know much about javascript, but I think the javascript code is actually wrong, I would appreciate is someone would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I want to display the href*

You need to fetch `href` property for that you can use `.prop()`

```
$('#display').html($('.menu a').prop('href'));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bYC7/)

Answer (score 2):

In case you mean retrieve the page and place it in the div:

```
// bind click event to all anchors within .menu
$('.menu a').click(function(e){
  // fetch the page using AJAX and place the results in #display
  $('#display').load(this.href);
  // prevent navigating away from the page (default action of anchor)
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

(Or maybe it's just me, but the question seems very hard to understand. :shrug:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); //this will keep your link from loading
  var href = $(e.currentTarget()).attr('href');
  $('#display').html(href);
});
```

Comment: FWIW, `.prop` is better suited for `href`, `id`, and other standard DOMNode _properties_.

Answer (score 1):

We can use an iframe to display the link in the `<a>` tag.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJT47/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version...

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <a  id="xxx" href="http://stackoverflow.com" onkeydown="myFunc()">HOME</a>
</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var data = $("a#xxx").attr("href");
  $('#display').html(data);
});
```